# Problemas ao exibir string javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$(function(){
    var curso = controller.getNomeCurso();
    $("#curso").text(curso);
});
```

O problema está na [linha 18](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/semestres.html#L18), pois não consigo exibir valores com caracteres especiais corretamente.

Exemplo: Ao enviar `Nutrição`, o valor exibido é `Nutri%C3%A7%C3%A3o`, mesmo na [linha 4](https://github.com/Jedarc/horariofacil/blob/master/www/semestres.html#L4) existindo uma meta tag definindo o *charset* como `UTF-8`.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara modifiquei a função controller com a dica do  @MarcusVinicius.

```
var controller = {
    getNomeCurso : function() {
        return window.decodeURIComponent(itens[0]); <-- window.decodeURIComponent("variavel para codificar")

    },
    voltar: function(){
        location.href = "turmas.html";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

tente assim:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: Não é problema de codificação, os caracters especiais estão codificados e não corrompidos.

Comment: Adicione charset ao seu js externo: <script type="text/javascript" src="*.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Tente também mudando a propriedade do charset para iso-8859-1

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas ajudas, mas infelizmente nenhuma das opções funcionaram. Também não intendi direito a dica de colocar o charset ao meu js externo.

Comment: é adicionar a propriedade charset="utf-8" ou charset="iso-8859-1" no seu link do seu js externo, assim quando a página solicitar o js, reconheceria a codificação.

Comment: Cara abri no IE e foi normalmente, porém no chrome me deparei com o problema da codificação, vou estar uma coisa e te aviso caso positivo.

Answer (score 1):

Ao que parece, a string está codificada. Se você utilizar a função `encodeURIComponent` na string *"Nutrição"* obterá *"Nutri%C3%A7%C3%A3o"*.

Então, para corrigir, utilize:

```
var curso = window.decodeURIComponent(controller.getNomeCurso());
$("#curso").text(curso);
```

```js
var curso = window.decodeURIComponent("Nutri%C3%A7%C3%A3o");
$("#curso").text(curso);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="curso"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: Eu tinha colocado o código errado, editei minha resposta. Tente de novo com o código: `var curso = window.decodeURIComponent(controller.getNomeCurso());`